# Even restart Tomcat can't update class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

It's a strange question, I restart Tomcat with Idea and it cannot update my controller class, when I request url which is my controller mapping path it is show old coding. To my surprise is whatever I update it cannot work. Even I delete this controller it still call this mapping path successfully and I don't know why. I restart Tomcat again and again even reboot my computer but not working. Have someone had this problem, please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you do not run and old war file that is lying around?

Comment: And also whether you have enabled automatic build and deployment(publish) for your project in your IDE.

Comment: Make sure the **Before launch** section in [Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html) has **Build artifact <name>** for the artifact that you [configure to deploy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts-to-deploy-dialog.html) to server.